# Почему Task.Result - свойство, а не метод?

Tags: .net

Оно все равно доступно только для чтения.

Comment: был бы метод - был бы GetResult

Answer (score 5):

У вас какое-то странное понимание того, что такое свойство (оставим за кадром здесь тот факт, что по факту свойства это и есть методы). 
Свойства очень даже могут быть только для чтения, это вполне нормальная практика. Более того, какой смысл был бы делать его методом, если оно не принимает никаких параметров и каждый раз возвращает один и тот же результат? Такое поведение характерно для поля (или для свойств, которые "интуитивно" выглядят как поля).

Если уж говорить о свойствах, которые должны быть методами, то хороший кандидат на роль метода - это DateTime.Now. Оно каждый раз возвращает разные значения, и это может сбивать с толку, отчего было бы правильнее сделать его методом.

Comment: Я только осваиваю C# после жавы, так что попрошу сильно не пинать :) Для метода очевидно, что он вызывает код. Свойство может возвращать существующую переменную, а может делать что-то больше. Или тут lazy property и результат кешируется? Так вроде нет.

Comment: >Свойство может возвращать существующую переменную, а может делать что-то больше. 

эмм..ну и что же? в чем противоречие?

Comment: В чем разница между методом и свойством в c#?

Comment: @SmitJohnth свойства - это те же методы, которые являются синтаксическим сахаром, выглядящим как поля. А потому и действуют они как поля, а не как методы

Answer (score 2):

Потому что так захотелось разработчикам.

Comment: А почему им так захотелось?