# ООП: свойства или методы?

Tags: c#, ооп, логика, теория

Доброго времени суток.

Наверное, вопрос может показаться глупым, но долю интереса он у меня вызывает.

На данный момент я не являюсь знатоком ООП, знаю некоторые концепции, но не умею их применять достаточно верно (как мне кажется).

В C# есть поля, а есть свойства и на данный момент я вижу удобным объявлять приватными поля и обращаться к ним через публичные свойства.

Однако же, как-то раз я совершил некоторую опечатку в коде и VS предложила мне замену (или вставку, точно я уже не вспомню) на что-то подобное (опять же, за точность не ручаюсь, на память):

```
public string GetName()
{
    return _name;
}
```

Как я понял, совершенно нет разницы, каким способом присваивать приватным полям значение: свойства или методы. В обоих случаях есть возможность добавить дополнительную логику для кода.

Важно ли это? Есть ли какие-нибудь рекомендации по этому поводу? Или совершенно не имеет значения, каким способом это делать и все завязано на привычках и предпочтения самого программиста?

Возможно, тот или иной способ следует использовать при определенных обстоятельствах?

Comment: Дубликат? http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/439103/10105

Comment: Оу, и правда, такой вопрос уже существует. Спасибо за ссылку.

Comment: Так удали свой вопрос или закрой его.